# Two Flowing Frames per Page

Tags: text-manipulation, layout

I want to write a document where the history, geography, culture of a certain place is the main text. Together with that, I want to present a timeline of events but, rather than a separated topic or chapter, the timeline should flow at the bottom of each page, independently of the main text of that page. And the timeline should not mess with possible footnotes the main text can have.

There is some way I can accomplish that?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: A very rough sketch to attempt to clarify.

[image: Very Rough Sketch]

Comment: Do you have a picture of what you want to achieve? Even a drawing on a napkin?

Comment: You can use the `[b]` option in a figure or table float with the timelines. By defaults this must allow only a bottom float per page. And you should read [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat).  What more?

Comment: A float is not useful, because the timeline will span more than one page. It has its own text flowing from a page to the next. The idea is not put content on it page by page, but write all text on it just once and that text flowing in the "bottom frame" for as many pages as it needs to take.

Comment: Mr. Werner, edited in an attempt to clarify.

Comment: @FabianoFagundes Then the word that you need to know is [flowfram](https://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram).

Comment: @Fran, thanks. It seems what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem seems solved by only indicating the package to use.